# CodeHS JavaScript - How to do a One Time Timer?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game with JavaScript in CodeHS. I would like to have a timer for an object go on for a certain time, say five seconds, before it ends. However, in CodeHS, it would repeat whatever is in the timer endlessly. How do I do a timer that only lasts for as long as I would want?

Thank you.

Comment: setTimeout is setting a timer for a callback-function.

Answer (score 0):

https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Animation-and-Games/using-timers.html

**Stopping a Timer**

> Timers will continue to run until they are given the command to stop.
> A timer can be stopped by issuing the stopTimer(functionName) command.
> The functionName should be the name of the function that was
> originally passed to the timer when creating it with startTimer().
>
> For example, Karel could create a timer that called a giveTreat
> function every 1000 milliseconds:

```
startTimer(giveTreat, 1000);
```

> Karel could then stop the timer by issuing the following command:

```
stopTimer(giveTreat);
```

So, using their example if you wanted to trigger your timer to run 5 times, once every second you could do something like this:

```
var Count = 0;

startTimer(giveTreat, 1000);

function giveTreat(){
    if(Count > 4)
    {
        stopTimer(giveTreat);
        return;
    }
    Count++;
}
```